# Clarification on Handlers, Threads and Executors when using a camera in Android Development

Tags: android, kotlin, handler, android-camera2, executor

I'm trying to implement the Camera2 API in my application. Having never done this before, I'm starting with [the Camera2Basic example code provided by android.](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2Basic/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/basic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt)

However, within the `createCaptureSession()` method there is a deprecated initialization method `CameraDevice.createCaptureSession()`, so I changed it to the following:

```
private suspend fun createCaptureSession(
    device: CameraDevice,
    targets: List<Surface>
): CameraCaptureSession = suspendCoroutine { cont ->

    // Create a capture session using the predefined targets; this also involves defining the
    // session state callback to be notified of when the session is ready
    var outConfig = mutableListOf<OutputConfiguration>()
    for (target in targets) {
        outConfig.add(OutputConfiguration(target))
    }
    var sessionConfig = SessionConfiguration(SessionConfiguration.SESSION_REGULAR, outConfig, cameraExecutor, object: CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

        override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) = cont.resume(session)

        override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
            val exc = RuntimeException("Camera ${device.id} session configuration failed")
            cont.resumeWithException(exc)
        }
    })

    device.createCaptureSession(sessionConfig)
}
```

However, in addition to the created Thread for the camera, now I also need an Executor, so now I have

```
/** cameraExecutor */
private val cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

/** [HandlerThread] where all camera operations run */
private val cameraThread = HandlerThread("CameraThread").apply { start() }

/** [Handler] corresponding to [cameraThread] */
private val cameraHandler = Handler(cameraThread.looper)
```

Having a `CameraThread` as well as an `cameraExecutor` is most likely wrong (I guess??). But how can I get a Handler from the Executor? Is this even the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation might resolve your problem:

As per [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/SessionConfiguration#SessionConfiguration(int,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration%3E,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback)):

> To dispatch events through the main thread of your application, you can use Context.getMainExecutor(). To dispatch events through a shared thread pool, you can use AsyncTask#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

You might get rid of the variable `cameraHandler` by using equivalent methods:
`CameraCaptureSession#capture` -> `CameraCaptureSession#captureSingleRequest`
`CameraCaptureSession#setRepeatingRequest` -> `CameraCaptureSession#setSingleRepeatingRequest`

and so on.
But be aware, that the  method you mentioned (`CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(java.util.List<android.view.Surface>, android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback, android.os.Handler)`) was introduced in API 24 and deprecated in API 30, but the [`CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(SessionConfiguration)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration)) was introduced only in API 28. So very probably You would need to handle API differences.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Is there any difference/up-downsides between the handler and executor variant?

Comment: Or in other words: Why are there so many different types/classes in android when it comes to multi-threading? Why not only have threads and coroutines (which are pretty much the equivalent if threads and tasks in c# if I understand correctly)?

Comment: Don't really know. I assume, that the system evolved quickly at the beginning and solutions were replaced with the tempo as well. Plus there were other popular libraries that took the responsibility of managing threads. That's why there are many solution for that.

Answer (score 4):

Handlers were what Android's API guidelines recommended for use for executing callbacks and such, until fairly recently.

However, they have various drawbacks compared to the more-general Executor, so now they are mostly recommended only when you want to run something on the "main" (also called the "UI") thread, which is mostly stuff that interacts with Views and other UI elements.  For one, a Handler will always bounce callback execution to the Looper thread it's associated with, and since most Android API callbacks originate on Binder IPC threads, that's one extra thread hop.  An Executor can be run in-place on that Binder threadpool thread, eliminating the extra hop in cases where performance really matters.

You can wrap a Handler in an Executor pretty trivially, for APIs that only accept an Executor ([one](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/HandlerExecutor.java;l=32) of many examples), so an Executor argument doesn't limit your options. The opposite isn't true.

So for the camera2 API, new overloads were added to everything to accept Executor where Handler was available before (and rearranging argument order so in Kotlin you can provide a callback lambda in an idiomatic fashion).  And we've depreacted some of the older versions of the methods so that it's clear which ones are the recommended ones now.

But there's nothing particularly wrong with the older Handler APIs, if they work for your use case. Internally they just wrap the Handler in an Executor anyway.

I would generally recommend having a single thread for running camera operations, and not make it the UI thread - opening and closing the camera device is slow, and you don't want to block your UI for ~1 second while starting things up. I'd avoid mixing use of both Handler and Executor since it might just get confusing for yourself, but the API doesn't care which you use for any given callback.

But if you have a Handler that posts to thread A, and an Executor that runs on thread B, you'll have to make sure you synchronize access to whatever info both A and B need to access, which is extra work compared to just running it all on one thread for camera.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the information - very helpful to clear up my understanding :)